# Why does 'apt-get source' fail with 'Permission denied' errors?

Tags: apt, permissions, source-code

I am getting following error when i try to fetch source for my current running kernel.

At present i am using following kernel:

```
ignite@ignite:~$ uname -a
Linux ignite 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP
Tue Oct 9 19:32:08 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I got following error. i have changed name http to htt because forum do not allow me to post many links.

```
ignite@ignite:/boot$ apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'linux' as source package instead of 'linux-image-3.5.0-17-generic'
NOTICE: 'linux' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/ubuntu/ubuntu-quantal.git
Need to get 106 MB of source archives.
Err http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main linux 3.5.0-30.51 (dsc)
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main linux 3.5.0-30.51 (tar)  
  Could not open file linux_3.5.0.orig.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main linux 3.5.0-30.51 (diff)
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux_3.5.0-30.51.dsc
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Failed to fetch http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux_3.5.0.orig.tar.gz
  Could not open file linux_3.5.0.orig.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Failed to fetch http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux_3.5.0-30.51.diff.gz
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
E: Failed to fetch some archives.
```

Please suggest how to resolve this error & fetch kernel source.

Comment: sudo apt-get install linux-source-3.5
 this command works.. i think i missed suo.

Answer (score 6):

You are asking apt-get to download the sources of the kernel and copy them inside your `/boot` directory. `/boot` is not world-writable, hence you are getting these errors:

```
Could not open file ... - open (13: Permission denied)
```

Just run `apt-get source` in an another directory, e.g. your home directory:

```
$ cd
$ apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Never place useless files outside your home directory. Using `sudo apt-get source` will surely do what you want, however your `/boot` directory will be polluted with useless files and directories. This is a really bad practice.